# salesforce authentication api not working for c#

Tags: c#, salesforce

I need to implement salesforce auth api in C#, but I'm not finding any proper way to do so.  I followed below link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/886855/Salesforce-API-integration-with-ASP-Net-applicatio

From where I get link for point 5. Add Web reference?